# `python filename.py` fails but `python3 filename.py` works on mac

Tags: python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

I have issue with importing packages
the file has just one line I.e, `import numpy`

So when I execute `python filename.py` I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError` whereas when I run the same with `python3 filename.py` it excutes without any errors.

All the versions that I have are 3.9 and above

Comment: You can always do a test running just python to open a py interpreter and see the version of that opened interpreter. Then python3 and see the version. Sometimes depending on the versions, one may have, for example, py 3.7 and another one 3.10, same with pip installing packages.

Comment: Run `which python` and `which python3` and you should see 2 very different paths. Meaning they are pointing to different package setups/environments and your `python` environment is missing numpy.

Comment: @Learningisamess so `which python` return 3.9.6 and `which python3` return 3.11.6

Comment: @M.K So ya I have 2 versions 3.9 (in-built) and 3.11 . Now how can I configure 3.11 as default version?

Comment: brew install pyenv

Comment: Then this just means that you installed the pip packages in the 3.11.6 version. I reocmmend not messing a lot with python paths. Using venv's or anaconda is a good way to have separate projects or "needs", each with the python version and library versions that you want. @TarunKumarS

Comment: Hey @M.K thanks for responding sir, really appreciate it. I am a student currently in my sophomore year with majors in AI and ML, I did a few internships in software development and now I am focusing on my majors. You being an expert in the field and was hoping to get a bit of guidance or places/things to watch out for. If you could share your email or any other contact info, would really really appreciate it. Thanks a lot sir 

Comment: Please do reply @M.K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we mentioned in the comments, your default python is `3.9` and python3 as `3.11`
The `module error` means that for one version you installed the packages, but for the other, you did not. You can figure this out with `which python` and `which python3`.

I recommend using environments for different projects that vary in libraries or python versions.

With venvs,create a venv with the python version installed you want.

```
python3.11 -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
```

Sourcing it, will show you in the console (myenv) at the beginning, meaning you are in that venv. if you install packages, they will be installed in this environment.

Similarly with anaconda:

```
conda create -n mycondaenv python=3.11.6
conda activate mycondaenv
```

To install packages you can install them with conda or pip if those are not available:

```
conda install numpy
pip install numpy
```

If you don't wont neither of these options, you can change the default version of python to use editing the .bashrc file:

```
alias python='python3.11'
```

And check

```
source ~/.bashrc
python --version
```

Comment: Thanks a ton mann. I searched everywhere about how to change the default version and nothing worked, so I was just running `python3 file_name.py` every time. This is so helpful .

Comment: I´m glad it helped. If it resolved the issue, make sure to mark it as a solution! @TarunKumarS